# Drag and Drop shadow on API 21

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-5.0-lollipop

Android's drag and drop api takes a shadow drawable as an argument, as demonstrated in [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html).  Now that Lollipop has shadows built into the framework with the elevation attribute, is it possible to use this with drag and drop?  Ideally I would like to make an the item animate up to an elevation.

Any ideas?  I realize this not be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The shadow drawable in the drag and drop has nothing to do with the shadow in material design. Infact, both are unrelated things. The shadow in drag and drop is the object you are going to see when you drag a view. However, the shadow in material design casts a shadow(english meaning shadow) to the drawable object called shadow. Hope, it was helpful.